# Как отправить данные на другой URL , в google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Есть google форма  и PHP  приложение,  после отправки get или post  запроса

***google-apps-script*** должен вернуть ответы на вопросы формы.

Как  сделать , чтобы google-app-script принимала запросы и отправляла ответы ?

Answer (score 1):

Разверните скрипт как WEB приложение. После этого будут доступны методы обработок POST и GET запросов.

Подробнее -  [в оф. документации:](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)